# Nexus One: 3G/WIFI Not Switching

Tags: wi-fi, 3g

As of last couple of weeks, my phone has been having problems automatically switching between wifi and 3G. When i leave home, I have to completely turn off the radio and turn it back on for it to pick up the 3G connection. When i come home in the evening, I have to turn off the wifi, and then turn it back on in order for it to kick in.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the phone doesnt automatically switch from WIFI to 3G and vice versa. If I go out of range of a known wifi hotspot, my 3G data connection should be established (indicated by the 3G icon in the top row), but it never shows up. If i work-around this by going in and out of airplane mode, the 3G connection is re-established.

My carrier is Optus in Australia, but i dont think that matters, given that it USED to work and only in the last couple of week has this problem occured.

Comment: I have a Nexus One myself (on Tmobile USA) have never seen anything like what you are describing. Could you please explain your problem a bit more clearly? Perhaps you can list step-by-step EXACTLY what you are doing? Also, who is your carrier

Comment: after going through (some) of the link from RevBingo, I suspect my problem is to do with a  having installed (and subsequently removed) Advanced Task Killer.

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I am experiencing similar issues on my S4.

Answer (score 1):

[This bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2207) seems to describe a similar issue.  The thread is a mixed bag of reports of various versions/apps/phones/networks either fixing or causing the issue, so you may need to dig through it and try some things to diagnose.

FYI, I don't have the problem on my Nexus One (O2 UK).

Answer (score 1):

I too have the problem with wifi sometimes. [wifi fixer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.wahtod.wififixer) seems to do the job of fixing it in most cases.

Except from that, as said before, this is a bug, so you may use that temporary fix until they hopefully fix that bug.

[image: qr of "wifi fixer"]