# New android user; switching between wifi and mobile data

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, connection-issues, mobile-network

When I leave the office my S4 doesn't seem to want to connect to mobile data. So, I end up with no connection at all. Turning mobile data off and on does nothing at all, I seem unable to establish a connection unless I restart the phone.

It happens occasionally in reverse also, if I go to work (or home, it is not exclusive to a single network) my phone maintains the mobile connection and wont join the wifi connection automatically (and sometimes I need to enter my password to connect to the wifi.)

Any ideas?

Note, my issue sounds the same as this one, though there is no solution there; [Nexus One: 3G/WIFI Not Switching](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/720/nexus-one-3g-wifi-not-switching)

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, it appears (at least in my case) that the app Skyvi was the problem. Almost all my Android issues (including random restarting) were sorted when I removed that app.